# iOS - Core data auto generated model - unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, core-data, selector, nsmanagedobject

I have a basic Core Data model which look like this :
[image]

I auto-generated data model files and it's give me something like that :

BSStudent.h

```
//
//  BSStudent.h
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class BSFormation;

@interface BSStudent : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * firstname;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * lastname;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * birthdate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id thumbnail;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *formations;
@end

@interface BSStudent (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addFormationsObject:(BSFormation *)value;
- (void)removeFormationsObject:(BSFormation *)value;
- (void)addFormations:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeFormations:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

BSStudent.m

```
//
//  BSStudent.m
//

#import "BSStudent.h"
#import "BSFormation.h"


@implementation BSStudent

@dynamic firstname;
@dynamic lastname;
@dynamic birthdate;
@dynamic thumbnail;
@dynamic formations;

@end
```

I tried to simply save a BSStudent object by doing the following :

```
BSStudent *newStudent = (BSStudent *)[NSEntityDescription entityForName:kBSStudent inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    newStudent.firstname = firstname;
    newStudent.lastname = lastname;
    newStudent.birthdate = birthdate;
    newStudent.thumbnail = thumbnail;

    NSError *error;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
```

But my app always crash with error : `[NSEntityDescription setFirstname:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f021e00`

Someone figuring out what's happening here ?

Answer (score 1):

One possible explanation is that you are using the wrong string in:

```
BSStudent *newStudent = (BSStudent *)[NSEntityDescription entityForName:kBSStudent inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

Try and check what `newStudent` actually is:

```
BSStudent *newStudent = (BSStudent *)[NSEntityDescription entityForName:kBSStudent inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
NSLog(@"New Student: %@", [newStudent description]);
newStudent.firstname = firstname;
```

maybe it will clarify things...

Comment: seems good with `newStudent.description` : `2013-01-26 16:49:34.641 Bulletin scolaire[3203:907] (<NSEntityDescription: 0x1cd96b80>) name BSStudent, managedObjectClassName BSStudent, renamingIdentifier BSStudent, isAbstract 0, superentity name (null) [...]`

Comment: maybe you are using an old version of your model, for some reason... have you tried cleaning the project, deleting the app from the device, and rebuild/run?

Comment: just tested to clean project + deleting app from device => same result :(

Comment: I found out where was the problem. I was using `[NSEntityDescription entityForName:...]` instead of `[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:...]`. Thx for your help sergio